# google maps static custom map marker disappears

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There is a tutorial im following on http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jcHqt/
Its a google maps with a static map marker the problem is im trying to replace the marker with a marker of my own the problem is when i try do that the marker completely disappears. any suggestions wht causing this problems.

```
 body,html,#map_canvas{height:100%;margin:0;}
 #map_canvas .centerMarker{
 position:absolute;
 /*url of the marker*/
 background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Azure.png) no-repeat;
/*center the marker*/
 top:50%;left:50%;
 z-index:1;
 /*fix offset when needed*/
 margin-left:-10px;
 margin-top:-34px;
 /*size of the image*/
 height:34px;
 width:20px;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your own marker's size is 128x128 px, you should set the css size to:

```
height: 128px;
width: 128px;
```

Maybe the margins should be adjusted as well.